# Reference an editable image in the CSS

Tags: wagtail

How can I reference an image, editable in the Wagtail admin, from a CSS file?

I am designing a page type that will have a `FooPage.banner_image` field. The field is editable for each page, in the Wagtail admin; it describes the image to use for that page, as background on the banner.

The page style for that page then needs to use the banner image, referencing a URL to that specific image. What reference can I write in the CSS, so that it will get “the `banner_image` for this page” as a URL?

Comment: Hey, I answered below but it is not super clear where you intend to use the URL. Do you need to generate a URL to use in the CSS in admin or on your main FooPage view? Either way it would probably be simplest to write your CSS within the page template using your style blocks and then using the normal image template code from here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/images.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are needing an image URL outside of the template - see the docs about [`Generating renditions in Python`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/advanced_topics/images/renditions.html#image-renditions).

To get a URL of an image, you need to generate a rendition and then get the URL of that rendition.

A rendition is what is generated when you pass in the resize rules (eg. `width-400`) in your templates.

To get a URL you can use this example code:

```
image_url = FooPage.banner_image.get_rendition('fill-300x186').url
```

OR get the original:

```
image_url = FooPage.banner_image.get_rendition('original').url
```